# Python scripting in arcmap - is there an easy way to re-compile py-file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, arctoolbox

in Arcmap 10.2.2 I am editing downloaded toolboxes (not python-toolboxes) by editing the python script in a texteditor. Whenever I restart Arcmap, the **Compiled Python File** gets updated and I can use the changes I made in my tool in Arcmap.

However, the Compiled Python File does not update without restarting Arcmap (which is time-consuming), why I can not make use of the changes I made without restarting.

Is there an easy way to update / re-compile the  **Compiled Python File** without restarting Arcmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways you can do this...If you are importing your module, you can do this:

```
import your_module
reload(your_module)  # will recompile .pyc
```

You can also use the built in `py_compile` module:

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile(r'C:\Path_to\your_module.py')
import your_module # should be reloaded
```

I recommend the first option.